# time of event not shown in android 2.2.2

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to add events to android calendar programmatically. Its all working fine in android 4 and above.But for 2.2.2 the time of the added event is not shown.The reminder for the event is added succesfully and shown in the event details but not fired. Why?

My code is:

```
beginTime=Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(year, month-1, day, hrs, mins);
endTime=Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(year, month-1, day, hrs+1, mins);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime",beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("title", title);
intent.putExtra("eventLocation", loc);
intent.putExtra("description", desc);
intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);
startActivity(intent);
```

I can't paste screenshots please help........

**EDIT:**
I just commented

```
 //intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
 //intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
```

These two lines and the time began to be shown!!!
That's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Android SDK Manager , Click Extras --->Select Android Support Library and Android Support Repository and install those two packages,

and then right click your project -->BuildPath-->Configure Build Path--->Add external jars-->

select --->android support-v4.jar into your project

so now and then every feature in 4.0 works for all versions

Answer (score 0):

I just commented

```
 //intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
 //intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
```

these two lines and the time began to be shown!!! That's all